# c# referencing error - The type or namespace name 'Extended' does not exist in the namespace 'EntityFramework'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference, visual-studio-2013

I imported the EntityFramework.Extended package from the NuGet Manager in Visual Studio, and when I put it in my using directive I get the following error.

```
The type or namespace name 'Extended' does not exist in the namespace 'EntityFramework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

so as you can see, it is referenced in visual studio, there is the error with the using statement and also the physical directory in my project, why am I having this issue...

**EDIT**
I got rid of the extended and am just doing:

```
 using EntityFramework;
```

That works fine but when I call the Delete method on my entity class it doesn't recognize the method? It says there is not method Delete for the class RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes deleting the reference and adding it back in helps. Then rebuild.

Comment: In your references (from your picture), double click the EntityFramework.Extended and have a look around. Make sure that the namespace is Actually what you think it is. also, Just noticed that you have other errors. You'll definitely need to correct those as well, though not sure what they are.

Comment: @MikeC. I added the other error in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the namespace for EntityFramework Extended is just `EntityFramework`. Example from the source code here: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Container.cs

```
namespace EntityFramework
{
/// <summary>
/// The default <see cref="IContainer"/> for resolving dependencies.
/// </summary>
public class Container : IContainer
{
```

You might be looking for the `EntityFramework.Extensions` namespace. From source code:

This class has a few `Delete` methods: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Extensions/BatchExtensions.cs

Comment: That works but it doesnt recognize the delete method when I use it lower down. Its posted in my edit

Comment: check my edit. You probably need the `EntityFramework.Extensions` namespace.